# How to reference PHP in Javascript

Tags: php, functions, javascript, variables

I'd like a php link for my Wordpress attachments to appear in part of a javascript function, but my below attempt does not output any text:

```
var link = "<?php echo wp_get_attachment_link();?>";
function myFunction(link) {
    return link;
}
```

Is this an issue with formatting?
Thanks!

Comment: PHP only runs on the server whereas JS runs client-side (in the browser).  To execute any PHP functions, you will need an Ajax call back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, no: It's not an issue with formatting, it's as jdm2112 explains the matter. You can, however, "send" the variable , or have it plucked  from the server, either via an Ajax call as jdm2112 suggests or as set by [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Which you use will likely depend on what the script does and when and how it's run.

Comment: If you want a global javascript variable, using `wp_localize_script()` is probably the best bet. If the variable is more dynamic, you'll want to use AJAX. You could start here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins